# Html.PasswordFor() unobtrusive field validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, passwords, unobtrusive-validation, model-validation

I've been trying to figure this out but am having no luck. I have a model with two properties: `Password` and `ConfirmPassword`.

If I display these as TextBoxes (`Html.TextBoxFor(...)`) in the view then the validation works fine. If, however, I display these as Password fields (`Html.PasswordFor(...)`) then the validation does not work until a form is submit.

Below is the code for both my view and model. Please note that the view is just a test view and I have not put a submit button on it.
Model:

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    [StringLength(40, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Shared_Editor_SecurityDetails), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PasswordLength")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm is required")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Must be the same as Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
</div>

<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
    @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword)
</div>
}
```

If anybody is able to help then that would be much appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is some security setting in the browser that stops javascript from reading paswords? Which browser are you using?

Comment: Hi @Stony, sorry for the late reply. I'm using Firefox and Chrome and get the same issue in both. I've tried to look for such a setting in both these browsers but can't find anything - does such a setting exist? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this was only a guess based on recalling reading about how insecure it was to let Javascript read passwords, because it left you vulnerable to attack.

Answer (score 1):

Although we didn't get to the root cause of this issue, we have come up with a workaround.

We set a function to be triggered on `blur()` for each of the password fields using jquery and the field id's. In this function we perform a `$(this).valid()` or `$('#idOfField').valid()`.

Equally you could perform this in the `keyUp()` function too.

This is forcing the validation but if anybody can come up with an actual reason as to why we may have encountered this issue I would be very intrigued to hear it.